# Are all the Taoists survivors?

Tags: black-cat

Before the events of *Black Cat*, Chronos apparently wiped out all the Taoists. When Shiki turns up he claims that he is a Taoist and that not even Chronos could wipe out an entire tribe.

After Creed defected his Apostles of the Stars are comprised of Taoists however Charden Flamberg and Kyoko Kirisaki had been traveling around giving away a potion which grants Tao Power to those who drink it.

I am wondering, are all the Taoists in the Apostles of the Stars are survivors from the war against Chronos or did some of them drink the potion? if so which ones?